# "I insisted on him going there" or "I insisted on his going there"

Tags: grammaticality

I am not sure about use if "his" or "him" in the said sentence. Please explain Which one is grammatically correct

Answer (score 1):

I insisted on his going there.

I insisted on him going there.

The word going is a gerund (noun).  So there should be a possessive verb in front of the gerund, not an object pronoun.  So the first sentence is more common and idiomatic.  But some people also use the object pronoun in informal conversation.

However, it's also correct to say:

He insisted that I go there (it's far more common).

He insisted that I should go there.

Comment: "He insisted that I go there"--shouldn't there be "went"?

Comment: @Rompey No, "insisted that I go there" is present subjunctive mood.

Comment: @joiedevivre After asking, I came across [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267981/if-someone-says-they-insisted-that-he-left-is-there-any-ambiguity-in-bre-or-i).

Comment: @Rompey I don't think there were terribly clear answers on that question. English, like German, has both a present and a past subjunctive mood. Past: If I **were**. Present: It is important that I **be**. Partly because English has very little verb conjugation, these moods are poorly understood and often not used. So, in colloquial speech, not using the subjunctive is common and sounds right. But the previously _more_ correct subjunctive is not yet _incorrect_. Does that make sense?

Comment: @joiedevivre - Frankly, not much. This is the issue I have to focus on.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Rompey Sorry! Open a chat with me sometime if you want to discuss it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Khan; although some (maybe even many, as @joiedevivre, a native English speaker,  maintains) people may use "me" in the similar context. Anyway, the usage frequency of "my" seems to be considerably higher [(see here)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insisted+on+my+coming%2Cinsisted+on+me+coming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsisted%20on%20my%20coming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsisted%20on%20me%20coming%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

The first Sentence is correct Grammatically if we remove on in a sentence. Just word Insisted is used in sentences if we talking about any person. Insisted on is used if we are talking about anything not about the person. Going is Gerund so it take objective case him.

Answer (score 0):

They are both grammatically correct, but there is a slight grammatical difference. In the first sentence, going is a verb; he was going there. In the second sentence, going is a noun; the journey was his.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, "his" is correct, as Khan said. However, English is evolving in such a way that many people say "him" and it will probably be the only correct answer in another 50 or 100 years.

Answer (score -1):

I think the latter one (I insisted on his going there.) is ,no doubtfully, correct but the former one (I insisted on him going there.) requires slightly changes in the formation as follows -

> I insisted him on going there.

Because In general cases, Prepositions follow the object (in nominative form), take an example -

**Take it off** not **Take off it**

Another example for better understanding,

**I am warning him about the hazard of water problem** Not
**I am warning about him the hazard of water problem**

It seems you have understood clearly the above slight differences.
Comment in, however, if you don't get that.

Comment: **Insist him on** is not grammatical. The verb **insist** is commonly followed by one of two constructions. Either **insist + (that) full clause** or **insist on (pronoun) gerund**. You can insist **that they are wrong** or you can insist **on them being wrong**. But you cannot insist them on anything.